# SharePoint setup

Tags: integrate-remedy-sp2013

I have project for a Japan company and I have problem about setup SharePoint. All element already installed. But set up SharePoint fail, have a message need setup Appfabric, but appfabric has already installed. Anyone can help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try re-installing the app fabric again ?

Comment: Yup. I'm Tried.

Answer (score 1):

This typically happens when Windows Server AppFabric is not installed correctly, especially if you attempt to install it by double-clicking on its setup file.

- Remove AppFabric from the Control Panel.
- Make Sure that you are working with the correct App Fabric version.
- Try to install it again as a command.

  .\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe /i CacheClient,CachingService,CacheAdmin /gac

> For more details check [**Windows Server AppFabric is not correctly configured During installing SharePoint Server 2013]**[1](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/windows-server-appfabric-is-not-correctly-configured-as-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites/)

Comment: I'll remember this.